# Retrieve nested data inside json in angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying to retrieve nested data under unique id inside local json file in angular.

here is what my json looks like

```
"uid111": {
"name": "name111",
"uid": "uid111",
"age": 22,
},
"uid211": {
"name": "name211",
"uid": "uid211",
"age": 26,
},
"uid311": {
"name": "name311",
"uid": "uid311",
"age": 24,
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read some JS docs on how to work with json data?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear I guess this is what you need

```js
jsonData:any[]=[]
readonly url='assets/json.json'
getData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url).subscribe((res:any)=>{
    this.jsonData=res
    }
    )
  }
  
 findObject(){
 let res = this.jsonData.filter((elm:any)=> {
    return elm.name=='name211';
});
console.log(res)
 }
```